# Git wont rewrite untracked file

Tags: git

I am having an issue with git.

**What I did**

late last night I commited and pushed couple of files. However it was to late and I did not notice that I did not git add one small file.

So this morning in office, when I noticed it, I decided to redo the work (since the file was small). After that I added a lot more stuff, and this time added and successfully pushed it to remote.

**What I want**

Now I am at home, with one untracked file and a lot of good changes in remote repository. I want to overwrite what I did last night with current changes, however git just seam not to care.

**What I tried**

```
git pull origin branch_name
git reset --hard origin/branch_name
```

I could probably just go and manually update the file, add it and re-commit but I would feel stupid. It seams that I am not using git like it was supposed so.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

There is something fundamentally odd about your question, which I will get to in a bit.  However, you should not *expect* Git to do anything with an untracked file.

#### Untracked files and Git's index

First, we should define this:  In Git, an *untracked file* is a file that is not in the index.

Well, OK, but now we have to define what Git's *index* is.  The index is at least a little bit mysterious, because there's no easy way to *see* it; but in Git, you have, at all times, *three* copies of every file **that Git knows and cares about**.  This last phrase, in bold, is the key to what's going on with untracked files.  It's important, though, to realize that while Git always has an index, what's *in* the index is temporary and changeable.  (This is different from commits!)

One copy of every file that Git knows about is the copy in the *current commit*.  This copy of the file *cannot be changed*, as it's stored in a commit and no part of *any* commit can ever be changed.

A second copy of this same file is, right now, in Git's index.  This extra copy is stored in the same compressed form that Git uses for all files.  Typically, it's *exactly the same* as the one in the current commit.  Duplicate files stored *inside Git*, in Git's own internal compressed form, take essentially no disk space at all.  So there's no extra disk space used up by this second copy, but the *fact that the second copy exists* is *how* Git knows about the file.

A third and final copy of the file is in your work-tree.  This third copy is *not* in Git's special internal Gitty form.  It takes real space—as much space as it takes; it's not compressed at all.  But this also means that every other program on your computer, including your editors and compilers and so on, can deal with the file.  (The special Git-form is only useful to Git itself.)

#### `git commit` makes a snapshot of the index

This gets us back to what an untracked file is: it's any file in your work-tree that's *not* in your index *right now*.  Moreover, it gets us back to one of the key purposes of the index, which is: ***The index contains the files that will be in the next commit you make.***

This is why you have to `git add` files all the time: `git add somefile` copies the contents of `somefile` into the version of `somefile` stored in the index.  The file is now *in the index*, if it wasn't before, and *matches the work-tree version*, if it didn't before.  And, now the next `git commit` will store *that version* of that file.

By running `git commit`, you make a new commit.  What's in the new commit is whatever was in the index at this time.  The new commit becomes the current commit; the index stays the way it is; and now every file *in* the index exactly matches the copy of the file in the current commit, because those were made *from* the copy in the index.  But this only commits the *tracked* files—only the files **that Git knows about**.

Since an untracked file is, by definition, not in the index, Git doesn't know about it.  It does not go into the next commit you will make.  It *is* not in the index now, so it *will not* be in any new commit.

Once you add it to the index, making it join with all the other files in the index, it *is* there and is now tracked.  Running `git commit` will make it permanent, stored as part of the new commit; the new commit becomes the current commit, and the file continues to be in the index, and thus continues to be tracked.

#### Which files are tracked? (again)

Obviously if you create a *new* file, and then `git add` it to the index and `git commit`, the set of *committed* files has just changed.  The old commit, the one that *was* current before, might have just a few files:

```
$ ls
README  afile   bfile
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ echo new file > nfile
$ git add nfile
$ git commit -m 'add new file'
[master 72536ab] add new file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 nfile
```

What's in the index *now* is the set of four files, `README`, `afile`, `bfile`, and `nfile`.  But that wasn't true for the *previous* commit.  Let's check it out:

```
$ git checkout HEAD^
Note: checking out 'HEAD^'.
[snip]
HEAD is now at 311a932... initial
$ ls
README  afile   bfile
```

What happened to `nfile`?  It's *gone!*  Well, in fact, it *is* gone, from *both the work-tree and the index*.  But it's safely stored, as a snapshot, in commit `72536ab...`, which is the last commit on branch `master`, and is the commit to which the name `master` points:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 72536ab (master) add new file
* 311a932 (HEAD) initial
```

(this repository is really not very interesting, as it only has these two commits).  If we check out `master` again, `nfile` *re-appears:*

```
$ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 311a932... initial
Switched to branch 'master'
$ ls
README  afile   bfile   nfile
```

The file `nfile` is now *in the index* and is therefore tracked.

When we switch *from* a commit that *does* have `nfile`, *to* a commit that *doesn't* have `nfile` in it, Git knows to *remove* the file, from the index and from the work-tree.

At this point the file does not exist at all.  There's no "untracked"-ness for it, it's just *not there*.

When we switch from a commit like `311a932...` that *doesn't* have it, to one that *does* like `72536ab...`, Git knows to *create* the file, in the index and in the work-tree.  Now the file exists and *is* tracked.

An untracked file is, then, a file that *does exist* but Git *doesn't know about*, by virtue of it being missing from the index.

The same file *probably* isn't in the current (HEAD) commit, but it could be.  For instance, we can remove `afile` from the index right now, without removing it from the work-tree:

```
$ git rm --cached afile
rm 'afile'
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    afile

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        afile
```

Note that the file is now simultaneously deleted *and* untracked.  This is because `git status` actually runs *two* comparisons.  The first one compares HEAD, the current commit, against the index.  There's a file `afile` in the current commit, but not in the index, so `afile` is deleted.  The second one compares the index against the work-tree.  There's a file `afile` in the work-tree that's not in the index, so `afile` is untracked.

#### The oddest part of your question

You said:

> Now I am at home, with one untracked file and a lot of good changes in remote repository. I want to overwrite what I did last night with current changes, however git just seem not to care. ...
>
> ```
> git pull origin branch_name
> ```

The `git pull` command does two things, and I always encourage beginners with Git to do them separately, because the first one is pretty safe and the second one ... well, we'll see.

The first part of `git pull` is to run `git fetch`.  The `git fetch` command has your Git, which is managing *your* repository, call up another Git.  That other Git has a different repository, but your repository and their repository generally share a lot of commits.

Your Git asks them: *What commits do you have?*  They will give back a list of branch names and commit hash IDs.  You can view this list directly yourself, by running:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
```

which has your Git call up their Git and get the listing, and then just print it.  When you run `git fetch origin`, though, your Git goes on to ask them for any commits they have that you don't, and then updates your own *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/branch_name`, to remember which commits went with *their* branch names like `branch_name`.

In this case, since you had uploaded some new commits to `origin`, presumably they had those new commits under their branch name `branch_name`.  Your Git will now have those commits in your repository, stored under your remote-tracking name `origin/branch_name`.  These are not (yet) in any of *your* branches, but they are remembered through this remote-tracking name.

At this point, you *usually*—but not always—will want to combine any work you have done locally to make new commits that you have that they don't, with any work you picked up from them through your `git fetch`.  You can do this combining with one of several commands.  The two most common are `git merge` and `git rebase`.

What `git pull` does is to run `git fetch` for you, and then *immediately*, without giving you any chance to consider things or change your mind, run one of those other two commands.  The idea here is that this will be more convenient for you than giving you a chance to look first, decide which if any command to run, and then run the command.  Sometimes that's actually true!  But sometimes it isn't.

Now, if you have an *untracked file* in your work-tree, that's a file that, by Git's definition, is not "safe".  It isn't even in your index, so Git can't assume it's safely saved away in any commit.  (If it *were* in your index, Git would have an easy way to test if it is safely saved in the current commit.)  If you run `git merge` at this point, and the incoming commit you want to merge with *does* have the file, the `git merge` command is going to *fail*, telling you that it would overwrite the untracked file.

So, presumably the `git pull` command failed.  You didn't show a failure, but probably it did fail—but if it did, it was probably the `git merge` part of the command that failed.

You then said you ran:

> ```
> git reset --hard origin/branch_name
> ```

Now, as long as your Git is at least version 1.8.4, this *should have* done what you wanted.  The `git fetch` step will have updated `origin/branch_name`, and `git reset --hard` tells Git to *throw out* whatever's in your current work-tree, replacing it with what you get by changing the current branch to point to the commit whose hash is stored under `origin/branch_name`.  The `--hard` implies `--mixed`, which tells Git to throw out the current index as well, replacing it with the contents extracted from the selected commit.

If your home Git is older than 1.8.4, however, this would all make sense.  The way `git pull` interacts with `git fetch` in older Gits *suppresses* the update of `origin/branch_name`.

If that's the case, all you have to do is run `git fetch` instead of `git pull`.  While these old versions of Git are pretty rare today, this is yet another reason I encourage those new to Git to use `git fetch` first, and only after it finishes, use some second Git command—which might not be `git merge` or `git rebase`, but instead `git reset --hard` just like this one particular peculiar case—*after* inspecting what `git fetch` fetched.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Though I have no idea why it failed because I was just - what the heck I'll re-clone the whole repository and continue working, I will most definitely try to do this in controlled environment and see what could have happened. I just had no idea why it failed silently but I'll figure it out. Your answer is awesome, haven't seen a lot of answers that are that good! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 2 version of one file. One of these files is in your git commit and another file is your untracked file. I suggest you first remove untracked file from your system.
You can use git commands like this:

```
git clean -fx
```

And you can see [this webpage](https://koukia.ca/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-branch-571c6ce9b6b1) for more information about how to remove untracked files.

If you have some useful information in your untracked file and git change it you will lose your file and you have no access to it, because it's a **untracked file**.